# Need example for derivative in relation to a product life cycle, please.

Tags: derivatives

I am looking for help in explaining how one would use derivatives in relation to a product life cycle, with a mathematical example. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.pearsonhighered.com/bittingercalcinfo/detail/sample-chapter/echapter/10e/files/assets/basic-html/page10.html

Comment: Thanks. I saw that one. I have watched videos on derivatives, I have a graph with a product life cycle on it...but I just can't seem to connect the explanation to a good example with a problem.

Comment: Remember what the derivative is. It is the slope of line tangent to the curve. You can, for example, use this information to deduce if your sales are increasing/decreasing. Does that make sense to you?